# If statement using 'and' in python

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to execute the if statement in python using 'and' but it's not executing i searched and tried other variation but still not working.
And I'm unable to find the reason why..?
Please can you help

Here is my code:-

```
#sensordata[1]=Up and sensordata[2]=OK

if (sensordata[1] == 'Up') and (sensordata[2] == 'OK'):
    print("successs")

print(sensordata[1])
print(sensordata[2])
```

output:-
Up
OK

This was not working

So I also tried :-

```
a=[]

a.append("1")
a.append("2")

if a[0]=='1' and a[1]=='2':
    print('working')
```

output:-
working

This is working

Can you Please help me what is the error in first code...?

Comment: what does `len(sensordata[1])` or `type(sensordata[1])` give? how are they initialized?

Comment: Hello, can you do `from pprint import pprint`

`pprint(sensordata)`

Comment: what's the value of `sensordata`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thnx for the help but Rakesh answer solved my query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a space in your string in the list.

Try:

```
if (sensordata[1].strip().lower() == 'up') and (sensordata[2].strip().lower() == 'ok'):
    print("successs")
```